# How can I disable the path summary text in an Apache directory index?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

Apache | CentOS

I'm using Apache with the Index directory option.  When users visit the web address, they see a path mentioned in text on that same page.  For example, they'll see the phrase: "Index of /misc".  Is there a way to remove this text summary of the directory the user is looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your customized header file in `httpd.conf`

Add this line to your `httpd.conf`

```
HeaderName header.html # path must be relative
```

Then create and place `header.html` into directory containing `httpd.conf` (`/etc/httpd/conf` for example).